# Getting a uniqe value in a link php not working

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I have a string of text, which I then grab a URL from with php regex. There can be any number of links, so I'm using

```
 preg_match_all
```

The problem is that for some reason when I put in one link, it's thinking that there are 3. When I do array unique it filters out the middle value, but not the last one.

Here is the code below

```
 $bodyMessage = imap_body($hMail,$idxMsg);
 $bodyMessage = quoted_printable_decode($bodyMessage);

 preg_match_all('((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)', $bodyMessage, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
 $links = array_unique($matches[0]);
 print_r($links);
```

The output of print_r($links) is:

```
 Array ( [0] => http://usnews.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2012/07/20/12861792-6-year-old-girl-confirmed-to-have-been-killed-in-colorado-theater-shootings?lite 
 [2] => http://usnews.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2012/07/20/12861792-6-year-old-girl-confirmed-to-have-been-killed-in-colorado-theater-shootings?lite
```

The body of the email that it parses is:

```
 --20cf300e4d7d02c34004c55e1489 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 @bill http://usnews.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2012/07/20/12861792-6-year-old-girl-confirmed-to-have-been-killed-in-colorado-theater-shootings?lite --20cf300e4d7d02c34004c55e1489 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable @bill
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Edit:

I followed the suggestion, by trimming, and that returns an empty array

```
 function trims($l){
                    trim($l);   
                }
                $links = $matches[0];
                $trimmedLinks = array_map("trims", $links);
                $trimmedLinks = array_unique($trimmedLinks);
                print_r($trimmedLinks); // = Array ( [0] => )
```

EDIT:

I think this might have something to do with grabbing the body message from imap. When i copy and paste the the string of text from imap, and set that  = to $bodyMessage, then it works...
Suggestions?

Comment: try array_map with trim before array_unique. My assumption is space at the end

Comment: Good suggestion, but that just returns an empty array. See my edit above

Comment: you've forgotten to return result from function :-) 'return trim($l);'

Comment: Oh, wow... long day argh. Still didn't work though :( the out put is: Array ( [0] => http://usnews.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2012/07/20/12861792-6-year-old-girl-confirmed-to-have-been-killed-in-colorado-theater-shootings?lite [2] => http://usnews.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2012/07/20/12861792-6-year-old-girl-confirmed-to-have-been-killed-in-colorado-theater-shootings?lite

Comment: put example that works .. this one just throws errors: http://codepad.org/2sgHWPoj

Comment: kaii... not sure what's going on with that codepad... there is no error when I run the code, but there is on codepad

Comment: @kaii Try this... http://ideone.com/Ehr6U it's weird, it looks like it's working there though... but not when I try anywhere else

Comment: Bill you need to read [the owner's manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). The `$matches` array is multi-dimensional with `matches[0]` containing all the overall matches (the URL), and `matches[1]` containing all the group 1 captures, etc. Also, using the parentheses as a regex delimiter is just confusing things here. Try: `'!(?:https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):(?://|\\\\)+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\\.&]*!'`

Comment: @ridgerunner I did that. When I use matches[1] I just get: 
Array ( [0] => http [1] => http [2] => http )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have pattern like this

```
((?:https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):(?:(?://)|(?:\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)
```

with non-capturing groups. If you put ?: in bracket, you'll get non-capturing group. And then an array will be:

```
Array ( [0] => http://usnews.msnbc.msn.com/_news/2012/07/20/12861792-6-year-old-girl-confirmed-to-have-been-killed-in-colorado-theater-shootings?lite )
```

Edit: The answer to this problem is to use imap_fetchbody instead

Comment: I updated the regex pattern and got an error... "Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0"

Comment: sry, try this: ((?:https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):(?:(?://)|(?:\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)

Comment: so you have one big group and it catches a link ;-)

Comment: That still returns multiple elements that are exactly the same when i do print_r($matches[0]) if I do array_unique to that then i just get index 0 and 2 but they are still the same

Comment: Adam, not sure what your comment is saying?

Comment: Yea, I just noticed that I was trying to debug... It works if I just copy and paste the string it outputs, and run it... but when it does it on it's own it doesn't work. That makes me think it might have something to do with imap or quoted_printable_decode

Comment: maybe try using imap_fetchbody()